# Allowing to download a google doc only if the file is shared publicly

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I know that when authorizing requests with OAuth, we can use several scopes to ask for a specific permission from the user. I want to ask for the permission for downloading files with publicly shared links (the user will actually provide this link).

However, the scopes listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) do not provide such an option. I do not want to get the permission for all the files and scare them.

Below is the code I am using. Any ideas? Do you think is it possible to get permission for the files with public links? Having access to the link shared can be utilized for this purpose?

```
private string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};

private DriveService GetDriveServiceInstance()
{
    UserCredential credential;

    using (var stream = new FileStream("Services/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        string credPath = "token.json";
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
              GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
              Scopes,
              "user",
              CancellationToken.None,
              new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
          Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
     }

     BaseClientService.Initializer bcs = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
     bcs.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
     bcs.ApplicationName = "synergy";

     DriveService service = new DriveService(bcs);
     return service;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way oauth works with google drive is that you are requesting access to a users full drive account.

> DriveService.Scope.DriveFile

[image]

Will give access to a users drive account but only access to the files which where opened or created with your client.

[image]

drive.readonly will give you full access to their full drive account to read and download files. There is no way to limit your access to only a directory, or only a group of files. its all or nothing.

Once you have access you can then search for the files you want as you now have access to their full account.